# How to drain the fuel tank on a first gen (2000) SV650?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, sv650

I’ve got some fuel line (top yellow fuel line in picture) from the petcock to a gas can. I disconnected the vacuum line. I read some cryptic hints about Mity-vacs and opening the throttle but connecting the Mity-vac to the vacuum line connector (middle yellow fuel line picture) and pumping it didn’t do anything with or without the throttle open.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What you are showing us in the picture is the fuel source coming off of the fuel tank, right?

Comment: Is that the same as a petcock? Yes. Sorry the picture may be too close up. It’s taken from the left side of the bike with the front end of the tank propped up. The bottom of the fuel tank is above, the airbox is lower left corner, the disconnected vacuum line is the black tube upper left, the disconnected fuel line is the yellow fuel line nearest the bottom of the picture.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9gZ6TmDz-g&t=6s

You are probably looking for something like this.

- Turn petcock to **off**
- Disconnect your fuel line from your carburetor and extend it somehow to a container.
- Turn your petcock to **reserve** (that way you will train the entire fuel)

It might take some time to drain the fuel. Leave it be and check occasionally. There should also be a way to drain it fast since I have heard of people stealing gas from motorbikes but I don't know how they do it.

This won't work if the bike is injected or your "petcock is vacuum operated". I personally am not a carburetor type of guy so you should cross-check this answer.(I would appreciate if a more experienced member could confirm or fix if necessary)

Comment: Hi Baron. Unfortunately it’s not that type of petcock. It doesn’t have a valve the user can turn. I’ve seen it called a petcock and it’s in that place on the bike, but I wonder if that’s really the right word for it.

Comment: [Suzuki COCK ASSY,FUEL Part # 44300-19F0V](https://www.suzukipartshouse.com/oemparts/a/suz/50d41237f8700230d8b512ad/fuel-cock)

Comment: VERY important but not mentioned.The engine has to be left to cool down and the container cannot be a "container" but a tank or jerry can FOR gasoline...